# Intro.js not highlighting elements inside ul

Tags: angularjs, intro.js

I have been using `angular-intro` js for tutorials tour in my mockup project.

It works fine except the elements inside the ul tag is not visible as intro-js helper layer overlays the element I have tried all the workarounds suggested but couldn't fix it.

Could anyone suggest me how to fix this?

Comment: you got the fix for this? same i am facing with fuse sidebar

Comment: Looking for fix too. Did you solve this problem?